# Reverse Mapping in TypeScript string enum

Tags: typescript, enums, jsfiddle

[According to the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime), TypeScript string enums are not supposed to do reverse mapping. But when I run the following code on jsfiddle it works:

```
enum Person {
 firstName = "First Name",
 lastName = "Last Name",
}

document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = Person["Last Name"];
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/u73x80e1/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSFiddle seems to be using an older version of TypeScript. They are generating the following JS:

```js
var Person;
(function (Person) {
    Person[Person["firstName"] = "First Name"] = "firstName";
    Person[Person["lastName"] = "Last Name"] = "lastName";
})(Person || (Person = {}));
document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = Person["Last Name"];
```

The same code on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) generates the following with every version you can choose on there:

```js
var Person;
(function (Person) {
    Person["firstName"] = "First Name";
    Person["lastName"] = "Last Name";
})(Person || (Person = {}));
document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = Person["Last Name"];
```

This appears to be an open issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1079. That thread states that they are using version `1.7.3`.

Comment: I was going mad on this for the last hour.... Any thoughts on why they changed the transpilation in newer TS? If I get the first JS correctly, it is essentially creating an enum with 4 fields instead of two (the original fields plus the "reversed" fields). Maybe this caused unintended behaviour?